# SQL Server GUI keeps freezing when accessing large amount of rows and data

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, database, user-interface

I am using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and and using RazorSQL a GUI to access a variety of databases. I am accessing a clients SQL Server (Microsoft 2008 R2) to generate a table from a query which contains over 5000 rows and has about 5 columns. One of the columns is an image data type. Each time I run the query it times out and freezes so I need to run xkill from my terminal just to close it out. I need to fetch all results for a project I am working on so I cannot just fetch 10 at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to prevent the GUI from freezing or can suggest a better GUI to use?

Here is the query perhaps its my query that is causing it?

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    , cast(b.Bytes as varbinary(max)) as Bytes
FROM
    (
SELECT DISTINCT
    a_inner.Number
    , a_inner.Latitude
    , a_inner.Longitude
    , b_inner.RetiredOn
    , b_inner.NonSaleable
    , a_inner.Name
    , a_inner.Zipcode
    , b_inner.Oid
    , c_inner.TabId
FROM
    "AM-Martin".dbo.CpCore_Site a_inner
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.CpSm_Face b_inner on b_inner.SiteId = a_inner.Oid
    INNER JOIN "AM-Martin".dbo.EyesOn_Face c_inner on b_inner.Oid = c_inner.Oid
WHERE
     b_inner.RetiredOn > GETDATE()
     AND a_inner.Number LIKE N'%LA%' OR a_inner.Number LIKE N'%LC%' OR a_inner.Number LIKE N'%BH%'
     AND b_inner.Latitude > 0.0
     AND b_inner.NonSaleable = 'False'


) AS a
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 
                Bytes 
            FROM "AM-Martin_bin".dbo.CpCore_Image b
            WHERE a.Oid = b.OwnerId) b;
```

Comment: How much memory do you have? How much memory is RazorSQL using? Have you considered contacting RazorSQL support? If an application is freezing I don't think there is anything your peers can do, except suggest trying not to return all 5000 rows to the app at once.

Comment: My computer has plenty of memory the actual GUI keeps running out of memory. I went to Razorsql support and I did what they instructed to do to increase the memory but it maxes out. This is why I am wondering if there is a better GUI out there? I am going to try fetching a few rows at a time to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it. RazorSQL only allowed a maximum of 324Mb I had to actually search that number in Sublime Text and I found the file that contained the code so I changed the max of 324Mb. The file was the razorsql.sh file and the code I changed is here and the line I changed is on the fourth line where it says 10000M (10GB):

```
#!/bin/sh
CWD=$(dirname "$0")
CMD="$CWD/razorsql.jar"
$CWD/jre/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx10000M -client -jar ${CMD}
RC=$?
if [ ${RC} != 0 ]; then
        echo "Error returned code found. Retrying . . ."
        $CWD/jre/bin/java -Xms256M -Xmx2048M -client -jar ${CMD}
        RC2=$?
        if [ ${RC2} != 0 ]; then
                echo "Trying local JRE . . ."
                java -Xms256M -Xmx2048M -client -jar ${CMD}
        fi
fi
```

They do not explain this in their support so I had to do some digging of my own.